# How recursive inner static class get initialized?

Tags: java, trie, static-class

i was looking into Trie data-structure and came across this piece of code

```
// R-way trie node
    private static class Node {
        private Object val;
        private Node[] next = new Node[26];
    }
```

i understood the logic, but what i don't get is, to what depth the Node will get initialized ?

you can check complete code at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/TrieST.java.html

Comment: If I understand way of thinking, "non static" internal class has specific life (hidden parent "this" reference etc), and "static" life is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no recursion here.

```
private Node[] next = new Node[26];
```

doesn't create any `Node` instance. It creates a `Node[]` (array of `Node` references) of 26 elements. All the references are initialized to null. The `Node` instances referenced by the array must be initialized elsewhere.

If, on the other hand, you had a member initialized as:

```
private Node n = new Node ();
```

that would cause an infinite recursion once the first instance of `Node` would be created.

Answer (score 0):

In your code Lines,
First you are inserting values using `put(val1,val2)` command in main method.

```
st.put(key, i);
```

Code lines for the `put(val1,val2)` method below,

```
 public void put(String key, Value val) {
        if (val == null) delete(key);
        else root = put(root, key, val, 0);
    }
```

according this code lines, the recursive else part is calling another `put(val1,val2,val3,val4)` method

Code line for the `put(val1,val2,val3,val4)` method below,

```
private Node put(Node x, String key, Value val, int d) {
        if (x == null) x = new Node();
        if (d == key.length()) {
            if (x.val == null) n++;
            x.val = val;
            return x;
        }
        char c = key.charAt(d);
        x.next[c] = put(x.next[c], key, val, d+1);
        return x;
    }
```

Here, when `x==null` then Node objects are initializing using `new Node();`.